# change ghost image in HTML5 drag and drop

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here I have some big div, but it ghost is too big for me, and I want to change it. Here is my solution:

```
<div draggable = "true" id = "ololo">
</div>
var k = document.getElementById("ololo");
k.addEventListener("dragstart", _drag, false);

function _drag(evt){
    var cl =  this.cloneNode(true);
    cl.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    cl.style.width = "10px";
    cl.style.height = "10px";
    cl.style.position = "absolute";
    cl.style.left = "1000px";
    cl.style.overflow = "hidden";

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(cl);
    evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(cl, 0, 0);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
       cl.parentNode.removeChild(cl);
    }, 1000);

}
```

[Jsffidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mondayguy/w745aLz9/) It works fine, but is it good use it in production? Why there is a scroll bar even I hidded it when it is overflow?

Comment: The scrollbar probably is because 'cl.style.left = "1000px";'

Comment: :D, I know, but I thought that if overflowed part will be styled as "hidden", it would not happen, where I'm wrong?

Comment: An element with visibility:hidden still "occupies space" in the view, it's only not showed. It's different from display: none; Better explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: @old_school - here is a [step-by-step guide](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html).

Comment: @ChrisBenseler the issue is the ghost div will be invissible, in this case

Comment: @TravisClarke This is bad trick, author not delete his ghost div, he just create a lot of copy and hide them with div which is backgrouded black

Comment: @old_school - I see what you mean, probably not the best idea now that you mention it.

Comment: @old_school - although you could still insert the `setTimeout`, like in the original post to remove the additional elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about hiding the clone behind the original draggable using a `z-index`, then incorporating the `setTimeout()` method to later remove it; preventing unnecessary duplication in the DOM.
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/v02s2wfw/3/)**

> This is an improved version of the step-by-step guide found at
> [kryogenix.org](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html)

**JS, CSS, HTML**

```js
document.getElementById("drag-coveredup").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
  var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
  crt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  crt.style.height = "10px";
  crt.style.width = "10px";
  crt.style.position = "absolute";
  crt.style.top = "0";
  crt.style.left = "0";
  crt.style.zIndex = "-1";
  document.getElementById("drag-coveredup").appendChild(crt);
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    crt.parentNode.removeChild(crt);
  }, 1000);


}, false);
```

```css
.dragdemo {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-coveredup" class="dragdemo" draggable="true"></div>
```

Comment: This works well in Chrome and Safari (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pxcwnb6j/) for a more accurate positioned version), but fails in Firefox.

Comment: Still doesnt work in firefox in 2023.